# CKEditor5 React memory usage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I use CKEditor5 on a react project. Each time a user opens the editor page the browser's memory usage increases. I put `editor.destroy()` to cleanup the state. But it seems it has no effect on memory usage because problem goes on.

It starts with a memory usage around 300 mb and then, after opening and closing tens of different pages with editor content, it goes up the 2000 mb or more.

What could be the reason?

```
// ... other packages
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import Editor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor';

function EditorPage(props) {
    const { editorContent } = useSelector(({ publisher }) => publisher.board);
    const [edited, setEdited] = useState(false);
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');
    const [editor, setEditor] = useState(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
        function handleSetContent() {
            const mContent = editorContent.type === 'q' ? editorContent.question.name : editorContent.option.desc;
            setContent(mContent);
        }
        if (editor && editorContent) handleSetContent();
        return () => {
            if (editor) {
                editor.destroy()
            }
        };
    }, [dispatch, editor, editorContent]);

    //** cleaned remaining code here//

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-1 flex-auto flex-col w-full h-full relative">

            <CKEditor
                editor={Editor}
                config={editorConfiguration}
                data={content}
                onReady={editor => {
                    // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
                    setEditor(editor);
                }}
                onChange={(event, editor) => {
                    const data = editor.getData();
                    setContent(data);
                    setEdited(true);
                    //console.log({ event, editor, data });
                }}
                onBlur={(event, editor) => {
                    //console.log('Blur.', editor);
                }}
                onFocus={(event, editor) => {
                    //console.log('Focus.', editor);
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default EditorPage;
```

Comment: I have the same issue and my editor build has no `.destroy()` method. Did you solve this?

Comment: not yet. I am still in contact with them. but very bad customer support

Comment: Actually, I built the editor from source and managed to get access to `.destroy()`, but no effect whatsoever

Comment: their reply: "I've verified this behaviour once again and it seems that the editor is properly destroyed after closing the dialog, so there's no need to call editor.destroy(), because the component handles this process itself. "

Comment: Then it is definitely a memory leak. A hard one to investigate I might say

Comment: found out that classic build works well... But custom build has a memory leak. Now investigating on what causes that leak